# OCaml Compilation #use error

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to compile an OCaml file with the debugger flag -g with the following line within the file -- #use "file2.ml".  Why does the file not compile as long as I have the use keyword in it?  What exactly does the "#use" keyword do?  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The directives starting with `#` are supported only in the toplevel, the OCaml interpreter, also known as a read-eval-print loop.

In the toplevel, `#use` causes the interpreter to read OCaml code from a text file. Afterward it continues to take commands interactively.

For compiled code, you should compile separately then link your modules together. If the code in `file2.ml` doesn't form a full module, you'll probably want to cut/paste it directly into the main file. OCaml doesn't have compile-time sourcefile inclusion like the C family has.

**Update**

Here's how to compile two OCaml files the old school way. You'll find there are those who say these ways are obsolete and that you should learn to use `ocamlbuild`. This may be correct, but I am old school at least for now.

```
$ ocamlc -o program file2.ml file1.ml
```

You have to list the `.ml` files in dependency order, i.e., a file has to be listed *after* any files it uses. This is already one reason to use a more powerful build tool.

Note that this does not behave the same as with `#use`, which loads all the top-level names of `file2.ml` into the global namespace. With separate compilation, names from `file2.ml` will be contained in a module named `File2`. If you want to call a function `f` defined in `file2.ml`, you should call it as `File2.f`.

Comment: Are you saying that the file2.ml needs to be compiled with file1.ml like this?
ocamlc -g file1.ml file2.ml

Comment: I don't know who says that using `ocamlc` directly is obsolete, but these persons are morons. Knowing at some point how the base toolchain work and the build artefact they produce is essential if you want to become a skilled OCaml programmer. I strongly suggest to read and re-read part III of the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/index.html#sec248)

Comment: If you want to become a skilled programmer it is a good idea to start programming in OCaml. OCaml infrastructure is already quite unfriendly to newcomers, so lifting a bar even more, by pointing them to a low-level tools is a way to a small and dying (but maybe elitist?)  community.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think it's fitting to clutter up the answers to beginner questions with debates on this issue. It's worth debating, but not in the answers to simple questions being asked by beginners.

Comment: sure, that's absolutely true.

Comment: @ivg I don't see anything particularly low-level in `ocamlc` and learning to use it is part of learning the language. The section of the manual I point to is one of the rare places where 1) the relationship between the module system and file names is explained 2) common errors from the compiler are explained. You get this completely wrong, hiding information is the way to build an elitist community.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR;

Use [ocamlbuild](http://nicolaspouillard.fr/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild-user-guide.html) to drive your compilation process.

```
ocamlbuild -clfags -g file1.native
```

### Deeper into the woods

`#use` is a special directive in the OCaml toplevel, in other words in OCaml interpreter. This directives are special commands that are executed by the interpreter for some effects. They are not part of the language. Moreover, different interpreters have different directives. If you want to write an OCaml program, then you need to compile, since OCaml is a compiled language.

OCaml comes with a very descent infrastructure, here is a short guideline. First of all, there're two compilers, bytecode and native. Bytecode is slow (still much faster than Python or Ruby), but portable. Native compiles to native machine code and thus very fast. If you have an access to both compilers, then use the latter. One can say, that native compilation is slower, I would say that on a modern machines the difference is negligible.

The plethora of tools is pretty large, we have `ocaml` for interpreter, `ocamlc` for bytecode compiler, `ocamlopt` for native compilation, `ocamldep` for finding dependencies between modules, `ocamldoc` for compiling documentation, `ocamlmktop` for making your own interpreters, `ocamlmklib` to bundle libraries, `ocamlrun` to run bytecode. Also we have `ocamlfind` to find libraries on your system. Fortunately we also have *One Tool to rule them all, One Tool to find them, One Tool to bring them all and in the darkness bind them*.

Here comes `ocamlbuild`. This tool is a part of OCaml language distribution, and it knows everything about all 9 minor tools. So you don't really need to learn them in order to start programming in OCaml. `ocamlbuild` will find all dependencies, link libraries, and create for you anything you want, including shared libraries or your own interpreters. For example, to link with `core` library, just pass `-pkg core` option. Moreover, ocamlbuild has `_tags` file, that allows you to store your arguments and save some space on your command line. So, other way to always pass `-g` option (not a bad idea, btw) to compiler is to add the following to your `_tags` file:

```
debug : true
```

And since, you're adding this `-g` option, I suspect that you're interested in backtraces. If that is true, then don't forget to enable backtracing recording with either calling to `Printexc.record_backtrace` or by setting environment variable `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with exactly the same problem, but the solution which I have found is to use the **#include** directive from the **cppo** preprocessor.  You can include the preprocessor in the **-pp** switch on the **OCaml** compiler.